# Cloud Functions for Firebase Time Out w/ wrong response

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Newbie question: Cloud Function times out every single time I run it.

In addition, it only returns ONE value, which is the first userId, in the Functions Log and none of its children.  Im assuming this is because it's calling the .once however, it's in a forEach loop, so I'm not sure what it wants.

Firebase database

```
-items
---- userId0123456789
   ---- randomKey987654321
       -- itemName
       -- itemDate
       -- itemType
---- userId987654321
   ---- randomKey012345678
       -- itemName
       -- itemDate
       -- itemType
```

And here is the function code...

```
  const key = req.query.key;

  **let userID = 'xxxxx';
  let ikey = 'xxx';**

  var dbRef = admin.database().ref('/items/{userID}/{ikey}');

                dbRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
                  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                    console.log(child.key+": "+child.val());
                  });
                });
```

UPDATE:  here is the entire function and now it's just timing out with no response.

```
'use strict';

// Firebase Functions
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Firebase Admin
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


// Default admin firebase configuration
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const rp = require('request-promise');
const promisePool = require('es6-promise-pool');
const PromisePool = promisePool.PromisePool;
const secureCompare = require('secure-compare');
const MAX_CONCURRENT = 3;

//Initial function call:
exports.CheckItemTypeinFB = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {


const key = req.query.key;


// Exit if the keys don't match
if (!secureCompare(key, functions.config().cron.key)) {
 console.log('The key provided in the request does not match the key set in    the environment. Check that', key,
    'matches the cron.key attribute in `firebase env:get`');
res.status(403).send('Security key does not match. Make sure your "key" URL query parameter matches the ' +
    'cron.key environment variable.');
return;
}



  // Try the database here...

  let userID = 'xxx';
  let ikey = 'xxxxx
  //create database ref
  let ref = admin.database().ref(`/items/${userID}/${ikey}`);
                //do a bunch of stuff



  ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
            console.log(`${child.key}: ${child.val()}`);
        });
        res.send(200, {/* response data */});
    });




  //send back response
  // res.redirect(200);


})  // END THE MAJJOR CONTAINER THINGS


 //  Returns an access token using the Google Cloud metadata server. */
function getAccessToken(accessToken) {
 // If we have an accessToken in cache to re-use we pass it directly.
  if (accessToken) {
    return Promise.resolve(accessToken);
 }

  const options = {
   uri: 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token',
  headers: {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'},
  json: true
 };

  return rp(options).then(resp => resp.access_token);
```

}

Help is much appreciated.

**Update:**. Timeout is fixed and it returns the userId's that are in the database under "/items". HOWEVER, if I use ${userId}/${key} I get nothing.  I'm still not able to tell how to get the children under random userId's in the database and none of the other posts I read explain it.     Firebase's docs state to use {userId} to get all under that wildcard but its not working.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the result of the `once` function or returning at all, so the function doesn't know when to finish hence the timeout.

```
let userID = 'xxxxxxxxx';
let key = 'xxxxxxxx';
let ref = admin.database().ref(`/items/${userID}/${key}`);

return ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(`${child.key}: ${child.val()}`);
    });
});
```

Also please be aware that the reference you are observing will give you the children of a particular user item (`itemName`, `itemDate`, `itemType`). If you want the items belonging to a particular user, adjust your reference path to be `/items/${userID}`.

When inside a HTTP trigger, you can send a response after observing the value.

```
exports.CheckItemTypeinFB = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    ...
    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
            console.log(`${child.key}: ${child.val()}`);
        });
        res.send(200, {/* response data */});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I must have misunderstood though when I was reading about {wildcards}.  It still has to be defined as a default and then replaced with whatever it actually is in the database?     I also had key defined as: const key = req.query.key;

Comment: also,     Using the above answer, I have no response in console and it still times out.

Comment: Okay, so you're inside a HTTP trigger so you need to make a response using `res`, for example, `res.send(200)`.

Comment: ah, I didn't mean to have that commented but same results with it uncommented....  time out with no results

Comment: Are you still returning?

Comment: getting an error: Error: could not handle the request after it times out.. I did notice that the variable "key" was being defined as the "key" that comes with the HTTP trigger to protect it so I changed the reference ${key} to ${ikey} and set a default value but I don't think that makes a difference ..... nope, it still times out w/ no response